# Ionic view not updating after return from provider promise

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm very new to Ionic and JS programming in general so please forgive my ignorance. I've been able to get data from other REST providers I've setup and have the updated values display fine. Pretty much copied the code from some other working functions. This time, no matter what I try, nothing will update.

Provider:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {

this.http.post(this.apiUrl)
  .subscribe(res => {
     resolve(res);
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            this.error = {"text":"App error occured."};
            console.log('Client-side error occured.');
        } else {
            this.error = {"text":"Cloud server error occured."};
            console.log('Cloud server error occured:'+err);
        }
        return this.error;
});
});
}
```

HTML:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Make</ion-label>
      {{vesselData?.make}}
    </ion-item>
```

Function:

```
vesselData = {"make":""};
updateVesselInfo() {

  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));

  this.vesselProvider.getVesselData(data.userData.sim).then(vData => {
      this.vesselData = vData;
  }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
}, (err) => {
  console.log("Vessel: ".err);
});
```

If I log the data returned from the provider in the .then(), it shows the provider returned the correct data. However, it's not updating any of the vesselData variables. Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Hey, which version of Angular are you using with Ionic 3?

Comment: ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.9.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

Comment: So CLI and ioni-angular package is not what Angular version you are using. Please check your package.json and name the following line: "@angular/core": "???"

Comment: @angular/core": "5.2.11

Comment: cool then see my comment and provided stackblitz. This should work

Answer (score 0):

So modern way is to provide method in your provider that returns Observable and then in your component you just call this method and subscribe to it to obtain data:

In your provider:

```
getVesselData() {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.yourErrorHandlerInsideProviderHere)
        )
}
```

Now in your component:

```
vesselData = {"make":""};

updateVesselInfo() {

  this.provider.getVesselData().subscribe( vesselData => {
      this.vesselData = vesselData;
  })
}
```

So ideal is to keep error handling inside provider here and within component your methods should be light weight.

This example should work for you as long as you are on Angular 4.3+ using modern HTTP module that comes with it.

Update:
Please ensure you properly bind to template. Here is example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wqrnl4
I skipped the rest call (http), but the principle is the same.

Comment: That didn't work. Same result. Data is returned but fields are not updated in the HTML.

Comment: It will work if you will do binding in the body of the ion-label. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wqrnl4

Comment: After trying your example and it failed, I deleted my .html and rebuilt it from scratch. That fixed it. No idea what was happening. I did change my provider and component to your code. Thanks.

Comment: Great, feel free to read more here : https://angular.io/guide/http. Angular’s documentation is pretty good about coding conventions